# ffmpeg x11grab a single window

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, xorg, grab

Is it possible with ffmpeg grab a window that is minimized or that not has the focus (there is another window over but ffmpeg records only the window which is below)?

With a command like `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 30 -i :0.0+x,y -f flv rtmp://url`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to capture a specific window with ffmpeg, the x11grab entry in the manual only refers to screens https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab and it suggests that the region you specify is static (if you move the window ffmpeg does not follow it):

However GStreamer offers some more flexibility in this case:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=0x04000007 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

This works with out-of focus windows and you can even move them but it does NOT work with minimized windows.

As you may know, you can get the window id with `wmctrl -l`.

You can see the options supported by GStreamer elements using the `gst-inspect-1.0` program, e.g.:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 ximagesrc
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if it was possible when this question was asked long time ago, but for the sake of completeness I had now success with:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 25 $(slop -D -f '-video_size %wx%h -i +%x,%y') out.mp4
```

Having `slop` installed makes this much easier, but the coordinates can also entered by hand of cause. It is then something like `-video_size 640x480 -i +0,100` to capture a `640x480` sized video with the topper left corner in position x=0 and y=100 (screen coordinates). The `-i [X],[Y]` syntax is not really intuitive.

Comment: This appears to be capturing a specific area of the screen, rather than a particular window (meaning if you move the window, you'll now be recording whatever was behind the window).

Comment: I have improved my answer and added the -D flag to slop. It allows a double click on a window and was introduced nine month ago in https://github.com/naelstrof/slop/commit/978e6e8d24cf74b365d2ee39a6fed36022dcf661

Comment: This answer assumes that you have graphics env which could not be always the case.