# Recording window application [Linux]

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I want to record a certain program window via FFMPEG, but x11 can't capture window.  Is there some way to do it on Linux?

On Windows I can do this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="System Monitor" -b:v 3M test.flv
```

But how can I do the same window capture on Linux via `title=System Monitor`?

x11grab does not support `title=`

Comment: Are you referring to a Microsoft Windows application, or a Linux application and you're having trouble getting FFMPEG to capture its window?  Can you provide more detail on your situation?

Comment: On Windows I can do this - `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="System Monitor" -b:v 3M test.flv`

But how can I do the same window capture on Linux via `title=System Monitor`? 

x11grab does not support `title=`

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1378465/

Comment: Hi @Yove, 
Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no feature to capture specific windows with x11grab in `ffmpeg`, but you can manually provide the coordinates to do so.

Use `xwininfo` to get the geometry of the target window:

```
$ xwininfo
  Please select the window about which you would like
  information by clicking the mouse in that window.
  [...]
  -geometry 80x24-61-68
```

This translates to a command in `ffmpeg` that looks like:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 80x24 -f x11grab -i :0.0+61,68 output
```

The recording area is fixed, so if the window moves it can go outsize of the recording area. It is also not exclusive, so if another window covers the recording area then that will also get recorded.

Comment: Please re-read the question, I know that x11 cannot capture window, the question is whether it is possible to capture a specific window, not the screen area

Comment: @Yove Your question did not elaborate this. New answer added.

Comment: Ugh.  My own use case for recording a specific window is to allow the window to be recording while it's behind something while I do something else on this screen.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that x11 cannot capture window, the question is whether it is possible to capture a specific window, not the screen area

Currently not possible using `ffmpeg` in Linux.

Comment: Do not know if there are any other ways to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Yove No, I am not aware of any other ways.

Comment: That is outrageous  [edit: ;-) ]